# Failed to determine a suitable driver class in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: maven, spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, mysql-connector

when running my spring-boot app, it throws the following error on google cloud.

```
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is 
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
```

my pom.xml :

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-socket-factory-connector-j-6</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.10</version>
    </dependency>


 SELECT VERSION();
    output:
    5.7.14-google-log
```

Anybody can help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Spring Cloud GCP Cloud SQL MySQL Starter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gcp/docs/1.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_spring_boot_starter_for_google_cloud_sql).
It will bring in the correct dependencies to connect.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-mysql</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```